# How do I log the the sum of values from multiple rows to a new row if the value in the column next to it matches

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

You will need this solve this.

[image]

In this sheet, I am trying to take the scores of the people and log them in the "Week Total" Column L as a sum. The names often exist in each column for that days score. I need to take their score for each day next to their name, and log it next to their name in Column L as a total if that makes sense.

So if Bob got a 10 on Monday, a 10 on Tuesday, and X the rest of the days, then I need to log that in Column L next to his name as "20".

I am using the Unique function to log all their names under Column K.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `query` and combine it with some array notations.

#### Formula:

```
=query({{A4:A,B4:B};{C4:C,D4:D};{E4:E,F4:F};{G4:G,H4:H};{I4:I,J4:J}}, "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''", 0)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- A duplicate `Bob` can be seen as you have spaces after Bob on some cells (e.g. `Bob` ). Make sure to have no spaces with them when inputting to remove duplicates from the formula result, or just use `trim` before using them. See modified formula before:

#### Formula with trim:

```
=query(index({{trim(A4:A),B4:B};{trim(C4:C),D4:D};{trim(E4:E),F4:F};{trim(G4:G),H4:H};{trim(I4:I),J4:J}}), "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''", 0)
```

#### Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You're not making your life easier by inputting `X` since that will be read as text, I'd recommend using 0 instead (if you insist on X then add an `IF` statement to exclude the Xs).

But what you're looking for is `=SUMIF()` coupled with some smart `Array notation` as demonstrated [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) in the documentation.

> Create arrays
> You can also create your own arrays in a formula in your spreadsheet by using brackets { }. The brackets allow you to group together values, while you use the following punctuation to determine which order the values are displayed in:

> Commas: Separate columns to help you write a row of data in an array. For example, ={1, 2} would place the number 1 in the first cell and the number 2 in the cell to the right in a new column.
> Semicolons: Separate rows to help you write a column of data in an array. For example, ={1; 2} would place the number 1 in the first cell and the number 2 in the cell below in a new row.
> Note: For countries that use commas as decimal separators (for example €1,00), commas would be replaced by backslashes () when creating arrays.

> You can join multiple ranges into one continuous range using this same punctuation. For example, to combine values from A1-A10 with the values from D1-D10, you can use the following formula to create a range in a continuous column: ={A1:A10; D1:D10}.

> Adding arrays to existing formulas
> You can also use arrays with other existing formulas using brackets in order to organize the returns from your formulas into rows or columns.

> For example, ={SUM(A1:A10), SUM(B1:B10)} will produce two values. The first cell will contain the sum of A1 to A10, the cell to the right will contain the sum of B1 to B10.